# SQL Server trim before and after specific values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database that has a column with a long string and I'm looking for a way to extract just a certain portion of it.

Here is a sample:

```
{
    "vendorId": 53,
    "externalRef": "38828059 $567.82",
    "lines": [{
        "amount": 0,
        "lineType": "PURCHASE",
        "lineItemType": "INVENTORY",
        "inventory": {
            "cost": 0,
            "quantity": 1,
            "row": "6",
            "seatType": "CONSECUTIVE",
            "section": "102",
            "notes": "http://testurl/0F005B52CE7F5892 38828059 $567.82 ,special",
            "splitType": "ANY",
            "stockType": "ELECTRONIC",
            "listPrice": 0,
            "publicNotes": " https://brokers.123.com/wholesale/event/146489908 https://www.123.com/buy-event/4897564 ",
            "eventId": 3757669,
            "eventMapping": {
                "eventDate": "",
                "eventName": "Brandi Carlile: Beyond These Silent Days Tour",
                "venueName": "Gorge Amphitheatre"
            },
            "tickets": [{
                "seatNumber": 1527
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

What I'm looking to extract is just http://testurl/0F005B52CE7F5892

Would someone be able to assist me with the syntax how to call my query that it will make a new temp column and give me just this extracted value for each row in this column?

I user SQL Server 2008 so some newer functions won't work for me.

Comment: Is the question about mysql or sql server? They're not the same thing.

Comment: I removed the [tag:mysql] tag, since the OP wrote that they use Microsoft SQL Server 2008. My understanding is that Stack Overflow suggests to the user to add the mysql tag for any SQL-related question.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 has been completely unsupported for over 2 years, you should be considering an upgrade urgently! The upside of this is that you'll be able to use the [inbuilt JSON functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) to parse your JSON. Failing that you'll have to use some quite ugly string parsing techniques with `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING` but SQL Server is not really built for this, so if you can either upgrade or do this outside of SQL that is going to be much, much easier.

Comment: you can use some function to get that information like https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/a-function-to-split-json-data

Comment: The isn't a "long string" it's JSON, and JSON can be consumed in all fully **supported** versions of SQL Server. If that isn't an *excuse* to get off your completely unsupported version of SQL Server, I don't know what is (as it seems being unsupported for 2.5 years isn't).

Comment: In modern versions of SQL Server you can do `JSON_VALUE(YourColumn, '$.lines[0].inventory.notes')`

Comment: @Larnu I hate to get technical, especially with you, I've seen you around. But since op is using a sql server version which doesn't support json, it really is just a long string. I've worked with people who had to work with older stuff than 2008 ;)

Comment: That doesn't make it *not* JSON, @HoneyBadger . The thing is, if the OP treats it like JSON, rather than a "long string", they'll have a much easier time. Unfortunately 2008 doesn't support JSON, but it's also completely unsupported, so the need to be able to consume JSON is just another reason why they should upgrade. Though there *are* solutions out there that consume JSON that aren't in-built. The OP could, if they really wanted, go down the CLR route, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade your SQL Server to a supported version.

But till then, we pity those who dare to face the horror of handling  JSON with only the old string functions.

```
select 
  [notes_url] = 
    CASE 
    WHEN [json_column] LIKE '%"notes": "http%'
    THEN substring([json_column], 
           patindex('%"notes": "http%', [json_column])+10, 
             charindex(' ', [json_column] , 
               patindex('%"notes": "http%', [json_column])+15)
               - patindex('%"notes": "http%', [json_column])-10)
    END
from [YourTable];
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=6323bb192120dd8fcccab4ffa3a511d4)*